# How to include database migration scripts in build artifacts

Tags: java, migration, liquibase, flyway

According to this excellent [article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html) from Martin Fowler:

> Once the build finishes successfully, the CI server packages the build artifacts and publishes them. These build artifacts contain the database migration scripts, so that they can be applied to the databases in downstream environments (...)

My question is how this is realized in practice for Java-based workflow? Build artifacts are normally .war, .jar or .ear files, and are published to Nexus, Archiva or Artifactory server. Can migration scripts be included in these artifacts, so that migration can be performed without any modification to target environments? Can tools like Flyway or Liquibase be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! We (Flyway) strongly recommend packaging your migrations with your application and running them on startup. This way you ensure that your database always contains the objects (tables, views, stored procedures, ...) the current version of your application expects.

Answer (score 0):

We use maven for building artefacts and we have flyway migration scripts under the src/main/resources/db/migration folder.

App is a spring web app and during spring container startup, it runs Flyway migrate. If there is a problem, the app never starts.

This way we ensure that database state is what the app needs when it starts.